# PHP Regex; extract first matching ID in WordPress shortcode

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, extract, shortcode

Having this string

```
$string = '[gallery link="file" ids="501,502,503,504,505,506,507,508,509"]';
```

How could I extract the first id in ids?

So far I have succeeded to extract all the ids, then used split;

```
$output = preg_match_all('/\[gallery.+ids=[\'"](.+?)[\'"]\]/', $string, $matches);
list($extracted) = split(',', $matches[1][0]);
```

There must be something simpler using only regex, right?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex to match the first id in id's,

```
\[gallery.+ids=\"\K[^,]*
```

OR

```
\[gallery.+ids=\"\K\d+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/uJ1vX5/1)

Your PHP code would be,

```
<?php
$string = '[gallery link="file" ids="501,502,503,504,505,506,507,508,509"]';
$pattern = '~\[gallery.+ids="\K([^,]*)~';
if (preg_match($pattern, $string, $m)) {
    $yourmatch = $m[0]; 
    echo $yourmatch;
    }
?> //=> 501
```

Comment: That was so fast! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> How could I extract the first id in ids?

Get the matched group from index 1.

```
\bids="(\d+)
```

Here is [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sE1gT5/3)

---

OR try with [Positive Lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
(?<=\bids=")\d+
```

Here is [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sE1gT5/4)

Sample code:

```
$re = "/(?<=\\bids=\\")\\d+/";
$str = "[gallery link=\"file\" ids=\"501,502,503,504,505,506,507,508,509\"]";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you are trying here looks weird. You don't need regular expressions to get the shortcode params. Instead use the default, built-in function from Wordpress.

Example from codex.wordpress.org:

```
// [bartag foo="foo-value"]
function bartag_func( $atts ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'foo' => 'something',
        'bar' => 'something else',
    ), $atts );

    return "foo = {$a['foo']}";
}
add_shortcode( 'bartag', 'bartag_func' );
```

See: [Wordpress Codex – The Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

**Update** – get the first ID:

```
// [gallery link="file" ids="501,502,503,504,505,506,507,508,509"]
function gallery_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'link' => 'file',
        'ids' => array(),
    ), $atts );

    $ids = explode( ',', $atts );

    // strip the first ID from the array…
    $first_id = array_shift( $ids );
    // …or just select it
    $first_id = $ids[0];

    return $first_id;
}
add_shortcode( 'gallery', 'gallery_shortcode' );
```

Comment: I'm not trying to add a shortcode as mentioned in your comment `add_shortcode()` I'm trying to parse a shortcode that a plugin embeds on a post content; `$post->post_content` .. the accepted solution above works well, thanks :)

Comment: @numediaweb `add_shortcode` already does all the parsing – that is what this function is for.

Comment: So, based on your answer; any idea how to extract the first id from `[gallery link="file" ids="501,502,503,504,505,506,507,508,509"]` using `add_shortcode()`?

Comment: I need the ID's prior to when this method is run so I can create conditional CSS and embed it properly in head